# Change header on s3 file

Tags: amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

If I have a file on s3 how can I change metadata of that file?

It looks like I can "copy" it to the same location with new headers which would effectively be the same thing.

I'm using [knox](https://github.com/Automattic/knox) as the node client to do this. The file in question already has the `Content-Type` header set to `video/mp4` but I want to change it to `application/octet-stream`. The reason for this is so that this link will trigger the browser to download the resource instead of displaying it in the browser window.

Link to [knox source](https://github.com/Automattic/knox/blob/0.9.2/lib/client.js#L480-L484) for this function

```
var filename = "/example/file.mp4",
    headers = {'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream"};

client.copyFile(filename, filename, headers, function(error, resp) {
  //response is successful
});
```

The response is successful, but when I reload the resource in s3 I don't see that headers have changed.

I can see that the underlying API call is this:

```
'PUT /example/file.mp4 HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream
x-amz-copy-source: /bucket/example/file.mp4
Content-Length: 0\r\nDate: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 21:13:12 GMT
Host: cc-video-archives-dev.s3.amazonaws.com
Authorization: <redacted>=\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
```

Comment: The API call looks right... copying an object onto itself is indeed how you modify metadata... but you have no `Cache-Control` headers, so you may be seeing a cached response.   Or you could be seeing a consistency issue in S3 -- newly created objects are guaranteed immediately available; overwrites and deletes are not guaranteed, even though they usually are almost immediate (though not always).  Check the object metadata in the S3 console?

Comment: Ah, interesting. So I am logged into the S3 console to check the metadata and it has not changed, still `video/mp4`

Comment: Actually, my mistake: the API call is *not quite* correct.  It's missing `x-amz-metadata-directive: REPLACE`.  If unspecified, it defaults to `COPY`.  Note that with `REPLACE`, *all* of the metadata is replaced with only what you provide, so if there is other metadata that you want to preserve, you have to fetch it and include it in the put/copy request. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are a lifesaver! Please write as an answer so I can accept...

Comment: Thank you for deferring to me, but I'll let you have this one -- feel free to post the solution as an answer, since I didn't actually have the knox-specific info, I just pointed you to the right place in the API docs.  Before you do, though, take a look at the knox source again -- it looks to me as if the ideal solution would use `copy` rather than `copyFile`, since copy *appears* to capture and preserve any other metadata that's already on the object... Take a look and see what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing this header:

`"x-amz-metadata-directive": "REPLACE"`

```
var filename = "/example/file.mp4",
  headers = {
    "x-amz-metadata-directive": "REPLACE",
    'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream"
  };

client.copyFile(filename, filename, headers, function(error, resp) {
  //response is successful
});
```